# sed: remove only a certain number of occurences of a specific pattern

Tags: bash, parsing, command-line, sed

Does sed provide functionality to remove a number of separate patterns in line, but not all of them?

For example: I have a text file with the list of directories in it, and I need to remove 3 slashes from the lines containing EXACTLY 4 slashes, not 3, not 5 — 4.

Before:

```
/foo/bar
/foo/bar/baz/quux
/boo/bar/baz
```

After:

```
/foo/bar
foobarbaz/quux
/boo/bar/baz
```

Comment: You seem to have the leading `/` missing in the last two lines in the input and output.  Is that correct?

Comment: I am sorry, corrected it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easier using `awk`:

```
$ awk -F/ 'NF==5{print $2$3$4"/"$5;next;}1' inputfile
/foo/bar
foobarbaz/quux
/boo/bar/baz
```

Comment: This solution is way easier than dealing with sed in some tricky way, thank you very much devnull!

Answer (score 2):

Match any lines that only has 4 `/` and perform the subsitution on those lines using `GNU sed` and `rev`:

```
% cat file
/1/2/3
/1/2/3/4
/1/2/3/4/5

% rev file | sed -r '\%(^[^/]+/){4}$%{s%/%%2g}' | rev
/1/2/3
123/4
/1/2/3/4/5
```

Comment: You probably missed `but not all of them`.  (The second line needs to have the last `/` preserved.)

Comment: correct, missed that, you can do `sed -r '/(^[/][^/]+){4}$/{s%/%%2g}' file` but that's from left to right tho so you would need to do `rev file | sed -r '/(^[^/]+[/]){4}$/{s%/%%2g}' | rev` awk probably is better for this.

Comment: Sorry, just clarifying, would there be any way other than saying: `sed -r '/(^[/][^/]+){4}$/{s%/%%;s%/%%;s%/%%}' file`

Comment: The only ways would be that or something along the line of what 1_CR did but both would be horrible for the case of line with 50 `/` say. @potong is the sed expert, he will know the clear way.

Comment: Aha! `rev`, that's nice. +1

Comment: Thank you sudo_O I'll try this one too. But so far... I do not understand what does the first backslash in the sed argument expression mean?

Comment: @ivx see backreference.org/2010/02/20/using-different-delimiters-in-sed/

Answer (score 1):

This is crude but works. Much prefer the awk solution

```
sed  's:^/\([^/]\+\)/\([^/]\+\)/\([^/]\+\)\([^/]*/[^/]*\)$:\1\2\3\4:' file
/foo/bar
foobarbaz/quux
/foo/bar/baz/quux/dust
/boo/bar/baz
```